# Is it possible to have a subset $A \subset X$ such that $\text{int}(A)\not\subset X$?

Tags: general-topology

I am following Stein's Complex Analysis text which regularly mentions a statement along the lines of:

"If $\Omega$ is an open set in $\mathbb{C}$ and $T \subset \Omega$ a triangle whose interior is also contained in $\Omega$..."

I thought since $T \subset \Omega$ then by default its interior must be contained in $\Omega$ as well. However since Stein mentions this explicitly, I am beginning to wonder if any counterexamples exist.

Comment: Which definition of $\text{int}(A)$ you are using?

Comment: There is no counterexample, since $int(A)\subset A$.
MAYBE the authors did this because when they say 'triangle' they mean 'the boundary of a triangle'.

Comment: @Infinity_hunter That all points in the interior of $A$ have some neighborhood centered at it which is contained entirely in $A$, this is the source of my confusion as this definition seems to imply the interior is automatically a subset.

Comment: I expect it comes down to what they mean by "triangle".  That is, whether or not the interior of a triangle is part of the triangle or not.

Comment: @Vitor Even then, wouldn't it be redundant?

Comment: @lulu In either case though, wouldn't it be repetitive to state the interior must also be contained in $\Omega$?

Comment: @CBBAM Then by definition  $intA \subseteq A$

Comment: @CBBAM no. If your region is, for example, $\Omega = \mathbb{C}^*$ and the triangle is centered at the origin, then the interior of the triangle is not contained in $\Omega$, but the boundary of it is! (Here the interior of the triangle is not the same as $int(T)$, clearly).

Comment: No.  it's easy to find open sets that contain the boundary of a triangle, but not the interior of it.

Comment: If, say, you were told that $\Omega$ was convex, then you'd be ok, but not for a general open set.

Comment: lulu: exactly! @CBBAM Note that the example I wrote above is not convex.

Comment: @Vitor Ah yes that makes a lot of sense now! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, we always have $\operatorname{int} A \subset A$. I do not have access to Stein's book, but  I am sure that what he denotes as a triangle is the union of three line segments (a special case of a closed curve in the plane). The region enclosed by the triangle is called its *interior*.

With this interpretation there is no guarantee that if $T \subset \Omega$, then also the interior of $T$ is contained in $\Omega$.

This interpretation of a triangle resembles that of a plane *Jordan curve* which divides the plane into an interior region and an exterior region.